# getting java.lang.VerifyError: org/ksoap2/SoapEnvelope in Android OS 4.1 and 4.2?

Tags: android, soap

I am working on an application in which I am calling webservices, which is working very fine in all the device with every OS version till 4.0 but when its crashing in my clients OS 4.1 and 4.2 it CRASHES at this point

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                        SoapEnvelope.VER11);
```

these are the crash logs:

```
--------- beginning of /dev/log/system
W/InputMethodManagerService(  399): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4249ded8 attribute=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@4224bfc8, token = android.os.BinderProxy@42aadd08
I/ActivityManager(  399): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher} from pid 399
I/ActivityManager(  399): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.weg.ecatalogue/.SplashScreen} from pid 774
I/ActivityManager(  399): Start proc com.weg.ecatalogue for activity com.weg.ecatalogue/.SplashScreen: pid=9283 uid=10071 gids={50071, 3003, 1015, 1028}
--------- beginning of /dev/log/main
I/dalvikvm( 9283): Turning on JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 10...
D/dalvikvm( 9283): GC_CONCURRENT freed 48K, 1% free 9269K/9348K, paused 4ms+3ms, total 34ms
D/dalvikvm( 9283): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 1% free 9267K/9348K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
I/dalvikvm-heap( 9283): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.753MB for 711664-byte allocation
I/ActivityManager(  399): Process com.google.android.apps.maps:LocationFriendService (pid 8602) has died.
D/dalvikvm( 9283): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 1% free 9962K/10044K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
D/dalvikvm( 9283): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2K, 1% free 9967K/10044K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 34ms
V/PhoneStatusBar(  642): setLightsOn(true)
I/ActivityManager(  399): Process com.google.android.gsf.login (pid 9058) has died.
I/ActivityManager(  399): Displayed com.weg.ecatalogue/.SplashScreen: +472ms
I/ActivityManager(  399): START u0 {flg=0x4000000 cmp=com.weg.ecatalogue/.HomeScreen} from pid 9283
D/dalvikvm( 9283): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 419K, 5% free 9803K/10252K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
I/dalvikvm-heap( 9283): Grow heap (frag case) to 10.184MB for 614416-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm( 9283): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2K, 5% free 10400K/10856K, paused 3ms+1ms, total 14ms
D/dalvikvm( 9283): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 2ms
D/dalvikvm( 9283): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 11ms
D/dalvikvm( 9283): GC_CONCURRENT freed 159K, 2% free 10706K/10916K, paused 2ms+4ms, total 30ms
V/PhoneStatusBar(  642): setLightsOn(true)
I/ActivityManager(  399): Displayed com.weg.ecatalogue/.HomeScreen: +470ms
I/ActivityManager(  399): Process com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox (pid 9165) has died.
D/dalvikvm( 9283): GC_CONCURRENT freed 146K, 2% free 11079K/11252K, paused 6ms+3ms, total 22ms
I/ActivityManager(  399): Process com.groupon (pid 9219) has died.
D/dalvikvm(  736): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2481K, 23% free 12154K/15596K, paused 3ms+5ms, total 63ms
D/dalvikvm( 9283): GC_CONCURRENT freed 167K, 2% free 11554K/11752K, paused 3ms+11ms, total 36ms
W/InputMethodManagerService(  399): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4271fb68 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@42813540
W/InputDispatcher(  399): channel '41f9a0e8 com.android.settings/com.android.settings.Settings (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
E/InputDispatcher(  399): channel '41f9a0e8 com.android.settings/com.android.settings.Settings (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
W/InputDispatcher(  399): channel '42316908 com.android.settings/com.android.settings.SubSettings (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
E/InputDispatcher(  399): channel '42316908 com.android.settings/com.android.settings.SubSettings (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
I/WindowState(  399): WIN DEATH: Window{42336178 u0 com.android.settings/com.android.settings.SubSettings}
I/ActivityManager(  399): Process com.android.settings (pid 26830) has died.
W/InputDispatcher(  399): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '42316908 com.android.settings/com.android.settings.SubSettings (server)'
W/InputDispatcher(  399): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '41f9a0e8 com.android.settings/com.android.settings.Settings (server)'
I/WindowState(  399): WIN DEATH: Window{42316908 u0 com.android.settings/com.android.settings.SubSettings}
I/WindowState(  399): WIN DEATH: Window{41f9a0e8 u0 com.android.settings/com.android.settings.Settings}
W/InputMethodManagerService(  399): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@426429d8 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@42813540
D/dalvikvm( 9283): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1279K, 11% free 11070K/12380K, paused 2ms+9ms, total 29ms
D/dalvikvm(20573): GC_CONCURRENT freed 387K, 6% free 9629K/10144K, paused 2ms+5ms, total 40ms
W/InputMethodManagerService(  399): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@426c4200 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@42813540
I/Gmail   (26984): MainSyncRequestProto: lowestBkwdConvoId: 0, highestHandledServerOp: 2669835, normalSync: true
I/ActivityManager(  399): Start proc com.google.android.gsf.login for service com.google.android.gsf.login/com.google.android.gsf.loginservice.GoogleLoginService: pid=9310 uid=10009 gids={50009, 3003, 2001, 1007, 3006, 1028, 1015}
D/dalvikvm( 9283): GC_CONCURRENT freed 742K, 12% free 10980K/12380K, paused 3ms+5ms, total 32ms
W/InputMethodManagerService(  399): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@42491c30 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@42813540
D/dalvikvm( 9283): GC_CONCURRENT freed 587K, 12% free 11010K/12380K, paused 3ms+8ms, total 46ms
W/InputMethodManagerService(  399): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@426e2e98 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@42813540
I/ActivityManager(  399): START u0 {cmp=com.weg.ecatalogue/.TabbarActivity} from pid 9283
D/dalvikvm( 9283): GC_CONCURRENT freed 606K, 11% free 11082K/12380K, paused 2ms+7ms, total 29ms
D/dalvikvm( 9283): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 627K, 15% free 10595K/12380K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
D/dalvikvm( 9283): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 64K, 13% free 10838K/12380K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
I/dalvikvm-heap( 9283): Grow heap (frag case) to 10.847MB for 249616-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm( 9283): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 13% free 11082K/12624K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
D/dalvikvm( 9283): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 73K, 13% free 11107K/12624K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
I/dalvikvm-heap( 9283): Grow heap (frag case) to 11.137MB for 279056-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm( 9283): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 12% free 11377K/12900K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
V/PhoneStatusBar(  642): setLightsOn(true)
E/dalvikvm( 9283): Could not find class 'org.kxml2.kdom.Node', referenced from method org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parseBody
W/dalvikvm( 9283): VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 315 (Lorg/kxml2/kdom/Node;) in Lorg/ksoap2/SoapEnvelope;
D/dalvikvm( 9283): VFY: replacing opcode 0x20 at 0x002f
E/dalvikvm( 9283): Could not find class 'org.kxml2.kdom.Node', referenced from method org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parseHeader
W/dalvikvm( 9283): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 315 (Lorg/kxml2/kdom/Node;) in Lorg/ksoap2/SoapEnvelope;
D/dalvikvm( 9283): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0003
E/dalvikvm( 9283): Could not find class 'org.kxml2.kdom.Node', referenced from method org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.writeBody
W/dalvikvm( 9283): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 315 (Lorg/kxml2/kdom/Node;) in Lorg/ksoap2/SoapEnvelope;
D/dalvikvm( 9283): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x000f
W/dalvikvm( 9283): VFY: array-length on non-array
W/dalvikvm( 9283): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x21 at 0x0007
W/dalvikvm( 9283): VFY:  rejected Lorg/ksoap2/SoapEnvelope;.writeHeader (Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlSerializer;)V
W/dalvikvm( 9283): Verifier rejected class Lorg/ksoap2/SoapEnvelope;
W/dalvikvm( 9283): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4143e930)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9283): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-13122
E/AndroidRuntime( 9283): java.lang.VerifyError: org/ksoap2/SoapEnvelope
E/AndroidRuntime( 9283): at com.weg.ecatalogue.servercommunication.WebServiceCommunicator$2.run(WebServiceCommunicator.java:78)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9283): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
W/ActivityManager(  399):   Force finishing activity com.weg.ecatalogue/.TabbarActivity
W/ActivityManager(  399):   Force finishing activity com.weg.ecatalogue/.HomeScreen
D/dalvikvm( 9283): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 62K, 12% free 11462K/12900K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
I/dalvikvm-heap( 9283): Grow heap (frag case) to 11.457MB for 249616-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm( 9283): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 11% free 11705K/13144K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
D/dalvikvm( 9283): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 61K, 11% free 11707K/13144K, paused 21ms, total 21ms
I/dalvikvm-heap( 9283): Grow heap (frag case) to 11.696MB for 249616-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm( 9283): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 11% free 11951K/13388K, paused 24ms, total 24ms
I/ActivityManager(  399): Displayed com.weg.ecatalogue/.TabbarActivity: +702ms
D/dalvikvm(26984): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1032K, 13% free 12414K/14128K, paused 8ms+4ms, total 64ms
D/dalvikvm(26984): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 40ms
E/WindowManager( 9283): Activity com.weg.ecatalogue.TabbarActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41f2c2c8 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-362,230} that was originally added here
E/WindowManager( 9283): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.weg.ecatalogue.TabbarActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41f2c2c8 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-362,230} that was originally added here
E/WindowManager( 9283): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:354)
E/WindowManager( 9283): at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:216)
E/WindowManager( 9283): at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
E/WindowManager( 9283): at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
E/WindowManager( 9283): at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:116)
E/WindowManager( 9283): at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:99)
E/WindowManager( 9283): at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:94)
E/WindowManager( 9283): at com.weg.ecatalogue.servercommunication.WebServiceCommunicator.callWebService(WebServiceCommunicator.java:72)
E/WindowManager( 9283): at com.weg.ecatalogue.listdata.DataSheetScreen.fetchElectricalData(DataSheetScreen.java:224)
E/WindowManager( 9283): at com.weg.ecatalogue.listdata.DataSheetScreen.onCreate(DataSheetScreen.java:177)
E/WindowManager( 9283): at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
E/WindowManager( 9283): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
E/WindowManager( 9283): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
E/WindowManager( 9283): at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2023)
E/WindowManager( 9283): at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
E/WindowManager( 9283): at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
E/WindowManager( 9283): at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:749)
E/WindowManager( 9283): at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:413)
E/WindowManager( 9283): at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:240)
E/WindowManager( 9283): at com.weg.ecatalogue.TabbarActivity.onCreate(TabbarActivity.java:25)
E/WindowManager( 9283): at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
E/WindowManager( 9283): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
E/WindowManager( 9283): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
E/WindowManager( 9283): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
E/WindowManager( 9283): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
E/WindowManager( 9283): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
E/WindowManager( 9283): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/WindowManager( 9283): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/WindowManager( 9283): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
E/WindowManager( 9283): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/WindowManager( 9283): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/WindowManager( 9283): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
E/WindowManager( 9283): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
E/WindowManager( 9283): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
I/Process ( 9283): Sending signal. PID: 9283 SIG: 9
I/ActivityManager(  399): Process com.weg.ecatalogue (pid 9283) has died.
W/InputMethodManagerService(  399): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 9283 uid 10071
D/dalvikvm(26984): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1185K, 13% free 12429K/14128K, paused 3ms+5ms, total 45ms
D/dalvikvm(26984): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 20ms
D/dalvikvm(26984): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1183K, 12% free 12448K/14128K, paused 5ms+4ms, total 43ms
D/dalvikvm(26984): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 17ms
D/dalvikvm(  642): JIT code cache reset in 5 ms (1048524 bytes 1/0)
D/dalvikvm(  642): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2261K, 35% free 17958K/27452K, paused 6ms+27ms, total 100ms
I/ActivityManager(  399): START u0 {act=com.android.systemui.recent.action.TOGGLE_RECENTS flg=0x10800000 cmp=com.android.systemui/.recent.RecentsActivity} from pid 642
D/dalvikvm(  399): GC_EXPLICIT freed 3440K, 22% free 34472K/43988K, paused 3ms+34ms, total 267ms
D/dalvikvm(26984): GC_EXPLICIT freed 785K, 13% free 12340K/14128K, paused 61ms+7ms, total 124ms
I/Gmail   (26984): MainSyncRequestProto: lowestBkwdConvoId: 0, highestHandledServerOp: 2669898, normalSync: true
I/Gmail   (26984): lowestBackward conversation id 0
W/Gmail   (26984): Scheduling index for 300000 ms from now
I/Gmail   (26984): Sending notification intent: Intent { act=com.android.mail.action.update_notification typ=application/gmail-ls (has extras) }
I/Gmail   (26984): Sending notification intent: Intent { act=com.android.mail.action.update_notification typ=application/gmail-ls (has extras) }
D/dalvikvm(26984): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1004K, 13% free 12420K/14128K, paused 3ms+4ms, total 40ms
D/dalvikvm(26984): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 32ms
D/dalvikvm(  642): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1358K, 30% free 19314K/27452K, paused 38ms, total 40ms
D/dalvikvm(  642): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 292K, 27% free 20267K/27452K, paused 25ms, total 26ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(  642): Grow heap (frag case) to 20.182MB for 380496-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm(  642): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 26% free 20639K/27824K, paused 23ms, total 23ms
D/dalvikvm(  642): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 28K, 26% free 20677K/27824K, paused 26ms, total 27ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(  642): Grow heap (frag case) to 20.583MB for 380496-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm(  642): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 26% free 21049K/28196K, paused 22ms, total 22ms
D/dalvikvm(  642): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6K, 26% free 21087K/28196K, paused 26ms, total 26ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(  642): Grow heap (frag case) to 20.982MB for 380496-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm(  642): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 25% free 21458K/28568K, paused 29ms, total 29ms
D/dalvikvm(  642): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6K, 25% free 21498K/28568K, paused 26ms, total 26ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(  642): Grow heap (frag case) to 21.384MB for 380496-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm(  642): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 25% free 21870K/28940K, paused 23ms, total 23ms
D/dalvikvm(  642): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 17K, 24% free 22002K/28940K, paused 27ms, total 27ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(  642): Grow heap (frag case) to 21.876MB for 380496-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm(  642): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 24% free 22371K/29312K, paused 26ms, total 26ms
I/ActivityManager(  399): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10704000 cmp=com.jv.falcon.pro/.activities.TweetListActivity} from pid 642
I/ActivityManager(  399): Start proc com.jv.falcon.pro for activity com.jv.falcon.pro/.activities.TweetListActivity: pid=9342 uid=10182 gids={50182, 3003, 1015, 1028}
I/ActivityThread( 9342): Pub com.jv.falcon.pro.TweetProvider: com.jv.falcon.pro.data.TweetProvider
D/dalvikvm( 9342): GC_CONCURRENT freed 148K, 2% free 9080K/9256K, paused 4ms+10ms, total 36ms
V/Falcon  ( 9342): STOPPING real time service manually
D/dalvikvm( 9342): GC_CONCURRENT freed 187K, 3% free 9335K/9552K, paused 3ms+4ms, total 27ms
V/TweetListFragment( 9342): ## Inital pos : 270
I/TweetListFragment( 9342): +++ Calling initLoader()! +++
I/TweetListFragment( 9342): +++ Initializing the new Loader... +++
I/TweetListFragment( 9342): +++ onCreateLoader() called! +++
D/dalvikvm( 9342): GC_CONCURRENT freed 123K, 2% free 9603K/9756K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 17ms
D/dalvikvm( 9342): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 13ms
I/TweetListFragment( 9342): +++ onCreateLoader() called! +++
W/GAV2    ( 9342): Thread[main,5,main]: Connection to service failed 1
W/ActivityManager(  399): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.START (has extras) } U=0: not found
W/GAV2    ( 9342): Thread[main,5,main]: Need to call initialize() and be in fallback mode to start dispatch.
D/dalvikvm( 9342): GC_CONCURRENT freed 73K, 2% free 9928K/10032K, paused 11ms+12ms, total 51ms
D/libEGL  ( 9342): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
D/libEGL  ( 9342): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
D/libEGL  ( 9342): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
D/OpenGLRenderer( 9342): Enabling debug mode 0
I/ActivityManager(  399): Displayed com.jv.falcon.pro/.activities.TweetListActivity: +1s17ms
V/Falcon  ( 9342): ## QUERY -- count = 370
E/TweetListFragment( 9342): +++ onLoadFinished() called! +++ false
D/dalvikvm( 9342): GC_CONCURRENT freed 64K, 1% free 10297K/10396K, paused 1ms+3ms, total 27ms
D/dalvikvm( 9342): GC_CONCURRENT freed 257K, 3% free 10455K/10740K, paused 3ms+10ms, total 40ms
D/dalvikvm( 9342): GC_CONCURRENT freed 244K, 3% free 10719K/10992K, paused 3ms+11ms, total 76ms
D/dalvikvm(  399): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2317K, 23% free 33903K/43988K, paused 137ms, total 139ms
D/dalvikvm(  642): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6239K, 45% free 16346K/29312K, paused 28ms, total 28ms
I/ActivityManager(  399): START u0 {act=com.android.systemui.recent.action.TOGGLE_RECENTS flg=0x10800000 cmp=com.android.systemui/.recent.RecentsActivity (has extras)} from pid 642
D/dalvikvm( 9342): GC_CONCURRENT freed 265K, 3% free 10988K/11300K, paused 6ms+8ms, total 64ms
I/GAV2    ( 9342): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: No campaign data found.
D/dalvikvm(  642): GC_CONCURRENT freed 237K, 37% free 18614K/29312K, paused 5ms+4ms, total 46ms
D/dalvikvm(  642): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 37ms
D/dalvikvm(  642): GC_CONCURRENT freed 110K, 27% free 21673K/29312K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 32ms
D/dalvikvm(  642): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 52K, 24% free 22446K/29312K, paused 26ms, total 26ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(  642): Grow heap (frag case) to 22.310MB for 380496-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm(  642): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 24% free 22817K/29684K, paused 52ms, total 52ms
D/dalvikvm(  399): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1423K, 23% free 34145K/43988K, paused 132ms, total 134ms
W/GAV2    ( 9342): Thread[Service Reconnect,5,main]: Connection to service failed 1
W/ActivityManager(  399): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.START (has extras) } U=0: not found
D/dalvikvm( 9253): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1114K, 17% free 9320K/11148K, paused 3ms+4ms, total 25ms
```

.....please suggest me .:(