# Why does "Could not find class" error occur only with Android 4.2 devices

Tags: java, android, android-ksoap2, android-4.2-jelly-bean

An app works flawlessly with all Android devices except Android 4.2 ones.

The app uses ksoap2-android, an imported Maven project that has been added to the build path of the app project. Again, the app works fine with all Android devices, but generates the following error with Android 4.2:

```
Could not find class 'org.kxml2.kdom.Node', referenced from method org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parseBody
```

org.kxml2.kdom.Node is a part of Maven dependencies of ksoap2-android.

What are the possible causes of this error unique to Android 4.2?

Comment: Possibly similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881131/getting-java-lang-verifyerror-org-ksoap2-soapenvelope-in-android-os-4-1-and-4-2

Comment: Yes, similar. I read that before posting my question.  I prefer using ksoap2-android as a referenced project to a referenced library jar which will be my last resort.